# Spring controller returns text on ajax call?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I implement my first ajax call with jQuery.

I typed such code:

```
$('#hostelSearchFormButton').click(
                        function(e) {                   

                            $.ajax({                            
                                headers: { 
                                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                                },
                                url : '${hostelSearchAjaxUrl}',
                                context: document.body,
                                dataType: "json",
                                data : $form.serialize(),
                                type : "POST",                              
                                cache: false,
                                async: true,
                                success : function(response) {
                                    if (response.status == 'FAIL') {
                                        for ( var val in errMessages) {
                                            var $errorLabel = $.find('#' + val
                                                    + 'ErrorLabel');
                                            $errorLabel.html(errMessages[val]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                error : function(data) {
                                    console.log("data on fail " + data);
                                }
                            });
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        });
```

It successfully posts to my @Controller method but as a resonse I have HostelAjaxResponse returned as json string in browser. I only see string in browser!

My method that handles ajax post. It's running ok but returns string:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody HostelAjaxResponse doSearch(@Valid @RequestBody HostelSearch hostelSearch,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Now I get nothing when ajax call is running. In chrome's javascript console I see error Bad Request :

```
POST http://localhost:8080/HostMe/hostel/search 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "returns string". It returns the correct string? What content-type is the response served as?

Comment: What Ajax Method should return instead of String?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I expect ajax call to run function on `success:`. This function should handle returned `HostelAjaxResponse` and change html elements via jQuery

Comment: But neither success nor error handler runs. Instead I see plain string in browser.

Comment: May be you are doing a form submit before ajax request. probably a submit button is there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are submitting the form to controller so when the response comes back you are not on the same page.You can check this by putting `"console.log"` in your done callback.

My suggestion is as you have already serialized forms data send it as data in ajax request.And just change

```
$form.submit(function(e){});
```

to

```
$("#submitbutton").click();
```

And check for returned response in success handler of ajax request.
I hope this will fix your issue.Cheers.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and still I have the same response. See my edits.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi: Add  dataType: "json",in your ajax request.

Comment: I added but it didn't help. What else you think is wrong?